# tensorflow 2 not finding gpu device

Tags: keras, gpu, tensorflow2.0, ubuntu-server

I have an ubuntu server with conda installed on it.  I created a virtual environment called tf-gpu and installed tensorflow 2 into it.  The ubuntu server has a geforce GTX video card with gpu installed.  When I run the code below in a jupyter notebook using the tf-gpu environment it shows 0 GPU available.  The modules installed in my tf-gpu environment are also shown below.  Why isn't my tensorflow2 environment seeing my gpu?  What do I need to do so that the tf-gpu environment can see and use the gpu on my ubuntu server?

code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

output:

```
Num GPUs Available:  0



# installed modules

$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/scotsditch/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
_tflow_select             2.1.0                       gpu  
absl-py                   0.9.0                    py38_0  
argon2-cffi               20.1.0           py38h7b6447c_1  
astunparse                1.6.3                      py_0  
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0  
backcall                  0.2.0                      py_0    anaconda
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    3.1.5                      py_0  
blinker                   1.4                      py38_0  
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38h7b6447c_1000  
c-ares                    1.15.0            h7b6447c_1001  
ca-certificates           2020.12.5            ha878542_0    conda-forge
cachetools                4.1.1                      py_0  
certifi                   2020.12.5        py38h578d9bd_1    conda-forge
cffi                      1.14.1           py38he30daa8_0  
chardet                   3.0.4                 py38_1003  
click                     7.1.2                      py_0  
cryptography              2.9.2            py38h1ba5d50_0  
cudatoolkit               10.1.243             h6bb024c_0    anaconda
cudnn                     7.6.5                cuda10.1_0  
cupti                     10.1.168                      0  
cycler                    0.10.0                     py_2    conda-forge
dbus                      1.13.16              hb2f20db_0  
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0    anaconda
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0  
entrypoints               0.3                      py38_0  
expat                     2.2.9                he1b5a44_2    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.13.1            he4413a7_1000    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.2               h5ab3b9f_0    anaconda
gast                      0.3.3                      py_0  
glib                      2.66.1               h92f7085_0  
google-auth               1.20.1                     py_0  
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.1                      py_2  
google-pasta              0.2.0                      py_0  
grpcio                    1.31.0           py38hf8bcb03_0  
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               hbbd80ab_1  
gstreamer                 1.14.0               h28cd5cc_2  
h5py                      2.10.0           py38hd6299e0_1  
hdf5                      1.10.6               hb1b8bf9_0  
icu                       58.2              hf484d3e_1000    conda-forge
idna                      2.10                       py_0  
importlib-metadata        1.7.0                    py38_0  
importlib_metadata        1.7.0                         0  
intel-openmp              2020.1                      217  
ipykernel                 5.3.4            py38h5ca1d4c_0  
ipython                   7.16.1           py38h5ca1d4c_0    anaconda
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py38_0    anaconda
jedi                      0.17.0                   py38_0    anaconda
jinja2                    2.11.2                     py_0  
jpeg                      9b                   habf39ab_1    anaconda
jsonschema                3.2.0                    py38_0  
jupyter_client            6.1.6                      py_0    anaconda
jupyter_core              4.6.3                    py38_0    anaconda
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1  
kiwisolver                1.3.1            py38h82cb98a_0    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.11                 h396b838_0    anaconda
ld_impl_linux-64          2.33.1               h53a641e_7  
libedit                   3.1.20191231         h14c3975_1  
libffi                    3.3                  he6710b0_2  
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0  
libiconv                  1.16                 h516909a_0    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               hbc83047_0    anaconda
libprotobuf               3.12.4               hd408876_0  
libsodium                 1.0.18               h7b6447c_0    anaconda
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libtiff                   4.1.0                h2733197_1    anaconda
libuuid                   2.32.1            h14c3975_1000    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.13              h14c3975_1002    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.9                h13577e0_2    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.2                he6710b0_1    anaconda
markdown                  3.2.2                    py38_0  
markupsafe                1.1.1            py38h7b6447c_0  
matplotlib                3.3.2            py38h578d9bd_1    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.3.2            py38h4d1ce4f_1    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4           py38h7b6447c_1000  
mkl                       2020.1                      217  
mkl-service               2.3.0            py38he904b0f_0  
mkl_fft                   1.1.0            py38h23d657b_0  
mkl_random                1.1.1            py38h0573a6f_0  
nb_conda_kernels          2.2.3                    py38_0  
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py38_0  
nbformat                  5.0.7                      py_0  
ncurses                   6.2                  he6710b0_1  
notebook                  6.1.1                    py38_0  
numpy                     1.19.1           py38hbc911f0_0  
numpy-base                1.19.1           py38hfa32c7d_0  
oauthlib                  3.1.0                      py_0  
olefile                   0.46                       py_0    anaconda
openssl                   1.1.1h               h516909a_0    conda-forge
opt_einsum                3.1.0                      py_0  
packaging                 20.4                       py_0  
pandas                    1.1.3            py38he6710b0_0    anaconda
pandoc                    2.10.1                        0  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py38_1  
parso                     0.8.0                      py_0    anaconda
pcre                      8.44                 he1b5a44_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.8.0                    py38_0    anaconda
pickleshare               0.7.5                 py38_1000    anaconda
pillow                    7.2.0            py38hb39fc2d_0    anaconda
pip                       20.2.2                   py38_0  
prometheus_client         0.8.0                      py_0  
prompt-toolkit            3.0.5                      py_0    anaconda
protobuf                  3.12.4           py38he6710b0_0  
pthread-stubs             0.4               h36c2ea0_1001    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py38_0    anaconda
pyasn1                    0.4.8                      py_0  
pyasn1-modules            0.2.7                      py_0  
pycparser                 2.20                       py_2  
pygments                  2.6.1                      py_0    anaconda
pyjwt                     1.7.1                    py38_0  
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                     py_1  
pyparsing                 2.4.7                      py_0  
pyqt                      5.9.2            py38h05f1152_4  
pyrsistent                0.16.0           py38h7b6447c_0  
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py38_0  
python                    3.8.5                hcff3b4d_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0    anaconda
python_abi                3.8                      1_cp38    conda-forge
pytz                      2020.1                     py_0    anaconda
pyzmq                     19.0.1           py38he6710b0_1    anaconda
qt                        5.9.7                h5867ecd_1  
readline                  8.0                  h7b6447c_0  
requests                  2.24.0                     py_0  
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                      py_0  
rsa                       4.6                        py_0  
scipy                     1.5.0            py38h0b6359f_0  
send2trash                1.5.0                    py38_0  
setuptools                49.6.0                   py38_0  
sip                       4.19.13          py38he6710b0_0  
six                       1.15.0                     py_0  
sqlite                    3.32.3               h62c20be_0  
tensorboard               2.2.1              pyh532a8cf_0  
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.6.0                      py_0  
tensorflow                2.2.0           gpu_py38hb782248_0  
tensorflow-base           2.2.0           gpu_py38h83e3d50_0  
tensorflow-estimator      2.2.0              pyh208ff02_0  
tensorflow-gpu            2.2.0                h0d30ee6_0  
termcolor                 1.1.0                    py38_1  
terminado                 0.8.3                    py38_0  
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0  
tk                        8.6.10               hbc83047_0  
tornado                   6.0.4            py38h7b6447c_1    anaconda
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py38_0    anaconda
urllib3                   1.25.10                    py_0  
wcwidth                   0.2.5                      py_0    anaconda
webencodings              0.5.1                    py38_1  
werkzeug                  1.0.1                      py_0  
wheel                     0.34.2                   py38_0  
wrapt                     1.12.1           py38h7b6447c_1  
xorg-libxau               1.0.9                h14c3975_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h516909a_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                h7b6447c_0  
zeromq                    4.3.2                he6710b0_2    anaconda
zipp                      3.1.0                      py_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3  
zstd                      1.4.4                h0b5b093_3    anaconda
```

when I run the below on my server I get the output below:

```
lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA
```

output:

```
42:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GV104 [GeForce GTX 1180] [10de:1e87] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

Comment: This is very hard to debug here in SO since there are many things that can go wrong, only you know what exactly was installed (CUDA versions, Nvidia drivers, etc), and also you claim to have an RTX GPU but lspci shows a GTX GPU (one that is kind of unreleased too!), so not enough and/or conflicting information.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy thank you for getting back to me.  I corrected the type-o from my original post to "GTX".  What additional info would you like me to supply?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by running

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

and then rebooting my server